# Why dont we transform X_test when using pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

I saw on an article https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-class-text-classification-with-sklearn-and-nltk-in-python-a-software-engineering-use-case-779d4a28ba5

```
   X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.25)
```

Step1: instead of doing these steps one at a time, we can use a pipeline to complete them all at once

```
      pipeline = Pipeline([('vect', tfidf),
                 ('clf', RandomForestClassifier())])
```

Step2 fitting our model and save it in a pickle for later use

```
      model = pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
      prediction= model.predict(X_test)
```

Normally, if we do manually

```
   X_train= tfidf.fit_transform(X_train)
   X_test=tfidf.transform(X_test)
   model=RandomForestClassifier()
   model.fit(X_train,y_train)
   prediction=model.predict(X_test)
```

My question is: If I follow the article, and perform these codes in step2 , do I miss this code

```
   X_test=tfidf.transform(X_test)
```

I don't see the author transform X_test. He just uses the original X_test. Is the author true?

After

Comment: what is the shape of `X_train` and `X_test` in the current setup ?

Answer (score 1):

> My question is: If I follow the article, and perform these codes in step2 , do I miss this code

No, the author is correct.

When calling `model.predict()`, the author is using the Pipeline class function `predict()`, and [as you can see in the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html#sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.predict)...

> Apply transforms to the data, and predict with the final estimator

So the X_test is first of all transformed and then used to predict the objective variable.